# safariwatir: how to select anonymous button

Tags: ruby, safari, screen-scraping, watir, safariwatir

I'm using watir for safari with ruby 1.8.7 on OSX Snow leopard.

I want to click a button, the only one in the page, that has neither id nor name. It only has an onckick property and the text within the tag..

How to do that? Is there a way to list all buttons on the page, and get the first (and only) one?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

I could help more if you have posted html of the button.

Something like this could do it:

```
browser.button(:index, 1).click
```

or

```
browser.button(:value, "Google Search").click
```

Not related to your question, but the best place for Watir questions is [watir-general](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/).